# Reset or recover GNU screen password

Tags: password, session, gnu-screen

I have a server where I wish to run a process using screen. I start a screen using:

```
screen -S <screen_name>
```

Detach using `ctrl+a+d`. But when try to reattach the screen using,

```
screen -r <screen_name>
```

It asks for screen password. Now I did not remember setting any password and the root user password do not work. How to reset this?

Comment: would `apt purge screen; apt install screen` be harmful (do you have data you would lose?) it's probably in a configuration file somewhere...

Comment: i have seen that.

Comment: it seems like there may be configuration settings in `~/.screenrc`; `purge` will not purge user-specific configurations. did you try deleting this file?

Comment: (it would be helpful for you to [edit] your question to include what you have and haven't tried.)

Comment: Have you seen [Password for GNU screen lockscreen command?](http://serverfault.com/a/169926/327404)

Comment: yes i have deleted `.screenrc` file. does not work. and purging does not work either.

Comment: @cat Deleting the `.screenrc` then purging make it work. thank you. If you would like to write an answer, I shall accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU Screen stores user's passwords in `~/.screenrc` and authenticates using [PAM in `/etc/pam.d/screen`](https://serverfault.com/a/169926/327404).

Deleting `~/.screenrc` should solve the problem.